# How to improve computational efficiency of correlation analysis using scipy on big dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, numpy, scipy, correlation

I have a couple of big data frames (12222 X 400000), on which I need to compute the Pearson correlation using `scipy`. The big data frame is generated by concatenating two other data frames. For example, here I can show can toy datasets which resembles my big data frame.

```
import pandas as pd,numpy as np
from scipy.stats import pearsonr

np.random.seed([3,1415])
cols = ['A_p','B_p','C_p','D_p','E_p','F_p','N_p','M_p','O_p','Q_p']
ind2 = ['sap1','luf','tur']

df1  = pd.DataFrame(np.random.randint(10, size=(3, 10)), columns=cols,index=ind2)
cols = ['G_l','I_l','J_l','K_l','L_l','M_l','R_l']
df2  = pd.DataFrame(np.random.randint(20, size=(3, 7)), columns=cols,index=ind2)
df   = pd.concat([df1,df2],axis =1)
df
 A_p    B_p C_p D_p E_p F_p N_p M_p O_p Q_p G_l I_l J_l K_l L_l M_l R_l
sap1    0   2   7   3   8   7   0   6   8   6   11  7   12  6   4   7   18
luf 0   2   0   4   9   7   3   2   4   3   14  6   6   14  18  8   10
tur 3   6   7   7   4   5   3   7   5   9   5   15  4   15  13  7   6
```

The function to perform  the correlation test is the following,

```
def correlation_analysis(lncRNA_PC_T):
    """
    Function for correlation analysis
    """
    correlations = pd.DataFrame()
    for p in [column for column in df.columns if '_p' in column]: 
        for l in [column for column in df.columns if '_l' in column]:
                    correlations = correlations.append(pd.Series(pearsonr(df[p],df[l]),index=['PCC', 'p-value'],name=p + '_' + l)
    
              
    return(correlations)
```

The function performs well on small data frames. However, on the big data frame of the above-mentioned size, it is taking forever to finish computing the correlation.

What I have tried to make small chunks of the data frame (`df1` and `df2`) and try running the list of the data frame. For example,like following,

```
n        = 2
list_df1 =  [df1.iloc[:, i:i+n] for i in range(0, df1.shape[1], n)]
list_df2 =  [df2.iloc[:, i:i+n] for i in range(0, df2.shape[1], n)]
```

Then, I passed the above lists into my function as following,

```
def correlation(list_df1,list_df2):
    correlations = pd.DataFrame()
    for dfs,dfs2 in zip(list_df1,list_df2):
        DF = pd.concat([dfs,dfs2])
        df = DF.set_index("Gene_id").T
        for p in [column for column in df.columns if '_p' in column]:
            for l in [column for column in df.columns if '_l' in column]:
                 correlations = correlations.append(pd.Series(pearsonr(df[p],df[l]),index=['PCC', 'p-value'],name= p + '_' + l))    

   return correlations
```

**The output for the datafrme should give pairwise correlations** between  all the columns with string `_p` and `_l`. For example, like this,

```
PCC p-value
A_p_G_l -0.944911   0.212296
A_p_I_l 0.994850    0.064639
A_p_J_l -0.693375   0.512246
A_p_K_l 0.585206    0.602027
A_p_L_l 0.162758    0.895922
... ... ...
Q_p_J_l -0.240192   0.845579
Q_p_K_l 0.101361    0.935361
Q_p_L_l -0.352381   0.770744
Q_p_M_l -0.866025   0.333333
Q_p_R_l -0.327327   0.787704
```

The current function is taking more than 12 hours to finish a datframe of size 1222 X 6222. Hence, an efficent solution would be really helpful. Any suggestions are welcome.
Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

You may have a look at `dask`, it is designed for the analysis of big data sets, supports pandas and has comes with multi threading support. I tested it on an extended version of you example (21x18) it showed a small reduction in computing time.

```
correlation_analysis w/o dask 0.767 sec 
correlation_analysis w dask 0.707 sec
```

`dask` also provides it's own routine for correlation calculation https://docs.dask.org/en/latest/array-api.html?#dask.array.corrcoef .

If the two variables you want to correlate (_p, _l) are in two dataframes, do you need to concatenate them? Looping over both dataframes instead of one merged reduced the computing time as well.

```
def correlation_analysis2(lncRNA_PC_T):
    """
    Function for correlation analysis
    """
    correlations = pd.DataFrame()
  for p in df1:
        for l in df2:
            correlations = correlations.append(pd.Series(pearsonr(df1[p],df2[l]),index=['PCC', 'p-value'],name=p + '_' + l))
```

```
correlation_analysis with 2 df  0.723 sec
```

You may look at https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/arrays.nditer.html how you can optimize your loops further.

Further possibilities might be to use of some JIT compiler (i.e. `pypy` or `numba`), but the effect might only be visible in larger test samples.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestions, I have never used `dask`.

Comment: The solution looing over with separate data frames is not improving any speed. Perhaps `dask` could help. I would try that. Thanks